# Dynamic Programming: Find shortest path through grid with obstacles

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the following problem from Skiena's *Algorithm Design Manual*:

> 8-16 Consider a city whose streets are defined by an X x Y grid. We are interested in walking from the upper left-hand corner of the grid to the lower right-hand corner. Unfortunately, the city has bad neighborhoods, whose intersections we do not want to walk in. We are given an X x Y matrix BAD, where BAD[i,j] = "yes" if and only if the intersection between streets i and j is in a neighborhood to avoid.
>
> (c) Give an O(XY) algorithm to find the shortest path across the grid that avoids bad neighborhoods. You may assume that all blocks are of equal length. For partial credit, given an O(X^2*Y^2) algorithm.

The question comes from the chapter on dynamic programming and under the heading "Graph Problems". I understand that I can model this as an undirected unweighted graph with vertices for all of the "good" intersections and edges between any adjacent "good" vertices. Given that this is an unweighted graph I can do a breadth-first search starting from the top-left vertex and once I reach the bottom-right vertex I have the shortest path.

Given that this problem is from the dynamic programming chapter I am trying to figure out how to solve this using dynamic programming. The shortest path to an intersection (i,j) is 1 + the minimum of the shortest paths to intersections (i,j-1), (i-1,j), (i,j+1), (i+1, j). This formulation doesn't seem to fit the overlapping subproblems nature of dynamic programing. Can this problem be solved using dynamic programming?

Comment: You might want to try posting this on the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, that formulation exactly fits the overlapping subproblems nature of dynamic programming.

In the first order, the shortest path to an intersection can be formulated in terms of the shortest paths to adjacent intersections.  Hence, subproblems.

In the second order, multiple intersections may share the same adjacent intersection for which its shortest path is an input in each of the other intersections' shortest path function.  Hence, overlapping subproblems.

On a side note, both Dijkstra's Algorithm and the Bellman-Ford Algorithm are examples of dynamic programming algorithms that will solve your example problem within the given big-O complexity constraint.

Comment: I'm having trouble coming up with the order to solve the subproblems because no matter what order I think of I don't have a solution to the necessary subproblems to solve it. If my dynamic programming matrix dp[i][j] represents the shortest path to intersection (i,j) I can't figure out an order to fill it in. Usually I have some recurrence where the value of a cell dp[i][j] only depends on cells from dp[0][0] to dp[i][j-1].

Comment: Something like this should work  : `dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j+1], dp[i+1][j], dp[i+1][j+1]) + 1;` depending on the fact whether or not you are allowed to move diagonally and the cost associated with each move and the base case can be `dp[X][Y] = 0;`

Comment: @MikeSweeney If you haven't taken a look at [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) or the [Bellman-Ford Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) before, I recommend you do so.  Dijkstra's Algorithm iteratively selects (evaluates) the node with the lowest total distance (from the start) from among the unselected nodes that are adjacent to previously evaluated nodes.  The Bellman-Ford Algorithm just updates the total distance for every node in the graph on every iteration.